# Jquery Load a div onclick event

Tags: jquery

By default content of first div will load then when a user click on  tag,contents of that div should load.

HTML:

```
    <a class="first">one</a>
    <a class="second">two</a>
    <div>
       <li id="first">
           <h2>pen</h2>
           <div>
               <div>parker</div>
           </div>
      </li>
      <li id="second">
            <h2>car</h2>
            <div>Bugatti</div>
         </div>
       </li>
    </div>​
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li#second").html();
    $("li#first").hide();
    $("a").click(function () {         
        var id = $(this).attr("class");  
        $("li#"+id).show().html();          
        $("li#second").hide();
     });
 });​
```

Now,when you click one,it will load but if you click two it will not load,i'm using `second.hide()`,how to get this working ?

Comment: The method call `.html()` will not do anything. It gets(!) the current HTML but you don't show or store it anywhere

Comment: @devnull69:My logic is wrong there so i need a way to display content on any div when clicked on <a> tag.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the call to .html() ?

Comment: @devnull69:Show the content of <li> tag.

Comment: @devnull69:I dn't thing you under stood my question,i know show() will show but my logic is wrong,when i click on second <a> tag,it is not showing content bcoz,i've used .hide(),where my logic is wrong so how do i get this working.

Comment: My comment is a comment because it's only a hint to something that is wrong and NOT a solution for your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently binding to every `a` click, and then you show the corresponding `li` to whichever link is clicked, but you always hide `#second`, regardless of whether or not it is `.second` that is being clicked.

You could bind them individually:

```
$('a.first').click(function() {
    $('#first').show();
    $('#second').hide();
});

$('a.second').click(function() {
    $('#first').hide();
    $('#second').show();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2mCgG/)

Or, if you want to address both in one listener:

```
$('a').click(function() {
   var id = $(this).attr('class');
   $('#first').toggle(id == 'first');
   $('#second').toggle(id == 'second');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Nek33/)

Comment: :When i click on second,it is removing second <a> tag.

Comment: @ram: Then you're probably toggling `.second` rather than `#second`. See my demos for working examples.

Comment: :<a> tags should be always there.

Comment: @ram: They are. See my demo. If the `a` tags disappear in your implementation then you're probably toggling `.second` rather than `#second`, or your markup is not exactly as you've pasted in your question.

Comment: :It is working now but when first time page load,i want to display contents of first tag only.

Comment: @ram: Then use `$('#second').hide()` in DOMReady, or `<li id="second" style="display: none;">`

Comment: :HOw do i add a hover effect on clicked <a> tag ?

Comment: @ram: This is an entire question altogether, and should probably be posted as a new question. There are several ways to do this, but you could use `addClass`, `removeClass` and `toggleClass` to set a class for the active link. For instance, in `$('a').click`, `$('.active').removeClass('active'); $(this).addClass('active');`, and in CSS `.active { color: green; }`